# How to enable Kerberos Authentication in Java Client Consuming .NET WCF service

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, authentication, kerberos

I am able to consume the WCF service with Kerberos authentication by setting the impersonal and client credential with the service proxy request.

Can this be done in Java?

Are there any Java libraries available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Kerberos authentication is configured on the server side, not client side.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
```

We set up the Kerberos credentials on the client end, which is usually done by the client proxy class.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "mydomain";
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "123456";
```

As for how to create the proxy in Java. Here are some solutions. There is a Web Service Client project template in Eclipse project templates, which could generate client proxy class with WCF exposed WSDL, like Adding Service Reference in C#.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Java_Web_Service_Client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client?view=netframework-4.7.2
There also exists Wsimport.exe tool in Java JDK, like SVCUTIL.EXE tool in .Net, which could generate the proxy by command shell.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/aa347733(v=vs.90)
There are also third-party libraries such as Axis2.
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi
Finally, you can even construct and send get/post requests through the HttpClient class to invoke the service.
Feel free to contact me if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: without any changes with on the Service side, how to set the impersonation from Java client

Comment: After you got the client proxy class, refer to the fowllowing code. ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "Test";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "123456";https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-impersonate-a-client-on-a-service